# How to automate saving the log of Network panel of Google Chrome Developer tools using Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, har

Suppose I open a web application and I want to get the details of all links,images and videos loaded in a HAR file from the Network panel of Google Chrome Developer Tools, how do i automate it?

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [devtools.network.getHAR](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_network#method-getHAR), you could use `chrome.devtools.network.getHAR` to get HAR log that contains all known network requests.

Comment: Could you please help me with a sample code? @HaibaraAi

Comment: @VinitShah, https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:devtools.network